# Opta-planner cloud balancing example

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using the cloud balancing example as a reference to a very similar problem. My model requires a dynamic processes adding/delete. I cannot find this feature it in the example.
How do you suggest to dynamically add/delete processes? Do i have to create a new cloudBalance problem instance, and call the solver ? Or i can modify the existing cloudBalance instance ? 
Thank you
-Sara

Answer (score 0):

See `AddProcessProblemFactChange` in optaplanner-examples.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey.  This is for the pannel gui , i dont use the panel gui. can i take this part of code as a reference to realy add/delete  process?